# MAMP PRO won't start on system Boot, OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: mamp-pro

After doing a fresh install of OS X Yosemite, I downloaded the latest version of MAMP PRO. I would like to have the server start on boot, I have the option checked. This use to would fine with OS X Mavericks. I uninstalled and retried and the same result. To start the server I must open MAMP and hit start. I am posting here due to the notice on their forum to redirect all question here. I looked in /Library/LaunchDaemons but their is no *.plist their for MAMP, but not sure if their should be. Any direction in solving this issue would be great.

Comment: Same here on two Macs with Yosemite. It's supposed to start /Library/StartupItems/MAMP at boot, but fails. "due to the notice on their forum to redirect all question here." - shows how much they care about their product!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug we are aware of and which will be fixed with the next update.

Comment: Thanks, It will save me from continuing to track this down on my system.

Comment: I wouldn't hold your breath - https://twitter.com/mamp_en/status/540476208212099072